# Wordpress WPAlchemy preview button

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not sure if this is a local issue, or prevalent in Wordpress, but I am using WPalchemy to build a plugin tool used to create various template areas within a product page.

When i click to preview the updates in Wordpress I can see that the database wp_filterpostmeta meta_value is automatically updating, thus updating the live site.

Is there a work around to preview the WPalchemy fields in edit mode, whilst not updating the live site?

Kind Regards.

Comment: You may try to ask your question in the [wordpress site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com), but I believe the previews, even if they update the DB, will not affect your published posts... Unless something has gone wrong (I mean very wrong). Since you are testing, I suggest not to use the live site for that. Dump the DB and create a local version with [XAMP/WAMP/LAMP/other](http://pikandeeweb.com/2014/09/difference-wamp-lamp-mamp-xampp/) to avoid troubles with live testing.

Comment: I am testing locally, to confirm the preview works correctly for all standard title and content areas, it is only the WPalchemy meta boxes that update on preview to live.